# Checking user group in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to have "user permissions" eg Admin, User. Im trying to make the side nav only display the link if the user is Admin

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.side_nav.helpers({  
  isAdmin: function(group) {
   console.log(group);
   return this.group === "Admin";
  }
 });
}
```

```html
{{#if isAdmin {{currentUser.profile.group}}}
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route='register'}}">Add User</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route='panel-remove'}}">Remove User</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route='panel-dashboard'}}k">Block IP</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route='panel-dashboard'}}">Edit Rules</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route='panel-dashboard'}}">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
{{/if}}
```

The template for the side navigation is called "side_nav". Not sure why it isnt working, When I put in the variable it just errors, when i put it in quotations mark it just outputs the actual string ({{currentUser..}}), When I hard code "Admin" into the if statement it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the value `currentUser.profile.group` to the `isAdmin` helper (not insert its value into the template), you'll need to drop the curly braces:

```
{{#if isAdmin currentUser.profile.group}}
```

I'm not sure what exactly the `isAdmin` helper is supposed to do, but if you want to check if the group passed in is `'Admin'`, then you should drop the `this`:

```
return group === "Admin";
```

Comment: I just realised the silly mistake I made xD It's too late for this. Thanks!